# py2app - Modules not found (conditional imports)

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I'm currently working on a personal project with Tkinter and I want to wrap everything into a macOS app.

Unfortunately, the command to create a production build not working and I always have an error related to "Modules not found"

```
Modules not found (conditional imports):
 * ConfigParser (dogpile.util.compat)
 * Cookie (requests.compat)
 * OpenSSL.crypto (urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl)
 * Queue (urllib3.util.queue)
 * StringIO (dogpile.util.compat, pkg_resources._vendor.six, requests.compat, six, urllib3.packages.six)
 * backports.functools_lru_cache (soupsieve.util)
 * cPickle (dogpile.util.compat)
 * colors (tkmacosx.variables)
 * com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * com.sun.jna (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * com.sun.jna.platform (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * cookielib (requests.compat)
 * copy_reg (soupsieve.util)
 * cryptography.x509.extensions (urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl)
 * regex (rebulk.remodule)
 * sympy (subliminal.score)
 * thread (dogpile.util.compat)
 * urllib2 (requests.compat)
 * urlparse (requests.compat)
 * win32com (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * win32com.shell (pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs)
 * yaml (guessit.options)
```

I've tried many workaround but nothing works..

The modules I use :

```
tkinter
subliminal
tkmacosx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check the version of pip and python you are using!
I had an similar issue where `tkmacosx`could not be imported.
Turned out I was using pip@3.10 but python@3.11
So using:

`pip3.11 install tkmacosx`

solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

The message about modules that weren't found is a warning, not an error.  These may or may not be problem, but often aren't. In particular the missing optional modules that are used from the various "compat" modules are almost certainly harmless if you use Python 3 (because those are imports of names in the Python 2 stdlib).

At first glance the missing "sympy", "regex" and "yaml" could be problematic, you could try installing these python packages.

As a bit of background, PyObjC shows 3 lists of missing modules at the end of a build (assuming there are missing modules in the category):

1. Unconditional imports:  These are imports that are always executed when a module is imported (toplevel imports and imports in class scope)

   These tend to be problematic, unless the module containing the import is itself optional.
2. Conditional imports: These are imports that are conditional, either because they are done in a function or because they are in some sort of conditional statement.

   These tend to be harmless.
3. Missing names in a "from FOO import NAME" statement: In these statements the "NAME" can refer to modules or to definitions in the imported module. Py2app reports these when it is not 100% clear that NAME refers to a module.

   These tend to be harmless, especially when the module ("FOO") is a C extension.

Comment: Hi Ronald, thanks for your explanation. I wanted to know why I cannot compile my app, so I've tried to rewrite everything and try to find the dependency or the line of code who crashed the application. So, after several tests, I find that when I add subliminal as a python import and compile the app won't work..

Comment: Do you get an error message when starting the app? The easiest way to see error messages is to start the app from the Terminal ("./dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp", replacing MyApp by the name of your app)

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I can debug with that! That's strange because I've got a module import error.
The module "babelfish" works in development but when I compile the app and run it I've got the error : 

`File "babelfish/language.pyc", line 178, in __str__
  File "babelfish/language.pyc", line 150, in __getattr__
  File "babelfish/converters/__init__.pyc", line 246, in __getitem__
  File "pkg_resources/__init__.pyc", line 2449, in resolve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babelfish.converters.alpha2'`

Comment: Finally, I found a solution to the previous error by using `python3 setup.py py2app --packages=babelfish` to compile my app. I always have an error due to compilation. The subliminal package I use cannot fetch subtitles. It seems to use xmlrpc_client.. it works in development mode but not with the compiled app.